# Debian and apt upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, update, maintenance

I have GNU/Linux Debian Servers (Etch/Lenny) in production. I want theses systems to stay up to date. I have installed apticron with tells me what packet needs an upgrade.
What is the good practice for production servers and stable releases of debian:

- always upgrade all packets (risky or not on debian stable?) OR
- only apply security updates (enough or not?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

once you got a Debian stable release installed (etch,for your example) you will not have anything but security fixes to install. Debian's **policy is not to change/upgrade the softwares within a given release** but just provide a fix for problems which has been discovered between two releases.

by the way, I wouldn't let anything do the upgrade but myself. A **malformed install/init script will make your system unavailable** in a minute, therefore you can and shall use download helpers, but do not let the upgrade process go unsupervised.

Comment: The point is what you are naming "a release", debian makes updates inside the same Major release (say Lenny for example), updating it from initial version to r1, r2 and so on.

Comment: the bug fixes are done by patches maintaining the same program version over the given (for example, etch) release. when a stable distribution gets old, security fixes are applied on the installation media (install dvds, cds), re-releasing them then incrementing r. Current release is 5.0.2 which is lenny r2. The next debian distribution will be called Squeeze r0

Answer (score 7):

I usually make every update on the stable branch, no problems for years and years even passing from a release to another.

My servers live with a daily, **manually run**, *upgrade-system* (great tool) and they have been updated and upgraded from Woody to Lenny quite simply.

Of course I do not make the updates via cron, I get only the updates availability this way.

In case of core packages such as glibc I first test the update on a non production machine, of course.

PS:
  I strongly recoment ***upgrade-system***, as it runs deborphan too and helps to keep the system up to date and clean at the same time

My 2 cents

**Edit:**
Note that inside a given release (Lenny for examples), could perfectly be a "sub-release", say 5.0-r1, 5.0-r2 and so on.
[image]

As reported in the wikipedia page on Debian, a stable release can be updated to fulfill security and/or **usability** issues:

*"stable, presently aliased lenny, is the current release that has stable and well tested software. Stable is made by freezing testing for a few months where bugs are fixed in order to make the distribution as stable as possible; then the resulting system is released as stable. It is updated only if major security or usability fixes are incorporated."*

The short answer to asdmin's opposition is that it is perfectly possible to have **non security related updates** even inside the same major stable release

Comment: Thanks for the upgrade-system flag, but you could get away with using aptitude for the same idea.

Comment: aptitude is much more interactive, upgrade-system instead makes everything needed just running it. de gustibus non disputandum est, of course :)

Comment: debian will not ship new softwares for stable distributions between 2 releases. all new packages will be security fixes on the same versions

Comment: @AlberT, of course.

Comment: about updates on usability issue: at debian, usability issue is not about cosmetics. most of the time, even from the highest demand from debian community, the release will stand, even it's not quite usable (see php+gd problem). btw it's the major reason why the freezing time is usually so long

Comment: @asdmin, nihil novi sub sole I think.

I suggest to take a look to the debian ChangeLog (http://www.debian.org/News/2009/20090627), libnet-rawip-perl is and axample, to immediately understand that fixes are done in subsequent release updates even if they are not strictly security related

Answer (score 3):

In this [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/51590/how-can-i-manage-apt-efficiently-on-multiple-machines) there's an answer pointing to the very promising **[apt-dater](http://www.ibh.de/apt-dater/)** program, where you can manage updates and install packages from a central location with a ncurses interface.

Comment: I didn't known about apt-dater, it seems good. Will try it. +1

Answer (score 1):

I have started using [cron-apt](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/162) after I asked a **[similiar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/3/best-practices-for-keeping-unix-packages-up-to-date)** and have found it to be quite useful.

Cron-apt downloads the updates and can send an e-mail when there are new differences so that you can manually upgrade.

I currently have it set up so that it checks for new updates every night and mails me the when there are new updates to be installed.

I only download and install updates for stable packages and usually do a short check on the release notes (if any) so that I know what I am actually upgrading.